# Dynamic BaseUrl in ExpressJs

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I'm trying to set the base URL for an Express app on startup.

I can hardcode the base URL and it works just fine:

```
app.use("/mybaseurl", routes);
```

However, if I try to use a variable instead which I can export on startup, it fails:

```
const baseUrl = "/mybaseurl";
app.use(baseUrl, routes);
```

The above doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Comment: What's the returning error ?

Comment: Cannot GET /test6/foo

Comment: `/test6/foo` ? Where does it come ? Does `test6` is your baseUrl ?

Comment: Yes. That the baeUrl I passed in via an environment variable. But I've seen what the issue was. The issue seemed to be with the fact that I was passing in the value in quotes via an environment variable. Works once I remove the quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

test this code, work for me: `http://localhost:3000/test`

app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const userRouter = require('./user');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

const baseUrl = '/test';

app.use(baseUrl, userRouter);

app.listen(3000, ()=> {
    console.log('Server is up on port ', 3000)
});
```

user.js:

```
const express = require('express');

const router = new express.Router();

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).send('hello');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: The issue seemed to be with the fact that I was passing in the value in quotes via an environment variable. Works once I remove the quotes.